# maven repositories

Tags: maven

I'm new to maven. I'm still failing to grasp the concept of it.

For example I'm looking for com.extjs:gxt:jar:2.2.5 or org.syslog4j:syslog4j:jar:0.9.46. I can't find them in any repo. Yet they seem fairly common packages.

Does that mean I have to download them by hand ? Doesn't it defeat the whole idea of maven ?

Where can I find a good repository that will have all these artifacts so that I don't need to download the jars by hand ?

What am I doing wrong when using maven, this definitely does not seem the way to go...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong.  The issue is that those artifacts don't exist in [maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/#browse).  By default, that's the only repository maven will download from.  You can add additional repositories (see maven docs) to configure repositories that aren't mirrored to central automatically.

Comment: So in the case of the two artifacts above, which repository am I to add ?

Comment: You should create your own corporate repo (e.g. try using http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/).

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael said, you are not doing anything wrong.

The default Maven central repository is not going to provide every possible artifact on the earth.

Normally you can have two way to solve it:

1) The artifact you use may be provided by some organization, which they provide their own repository to host those artifact.  Tell Maven to lookup those repositories so that Maven can retrieve the corresponding artifact.

or

2) Get the JAR etc and put in your local environment.

There are two most commonly used ways for the above work:

A) Have a "local" maven repository/proxy (e.g. Nexus, Artifactory), and make your Maven points to this repository.  Adding new remote repository (1) is mostly done by adding extra repo to proxy under your local Maven repo.  Manually handling 3rd party artifact (2) is done by deploying the JAR to your local repo.

B) All done locally by your local Maven.  Adding new remote repo (1) is done by updating the settings.xml (or your project POM.xml).  Manually handling 3rd party artifact (2) is done by installing 3rd party JAR to local repository.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.extjs</groupId>
        <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-gwt22</version>
    </dependency>
```